# XML throwing error on using Circle ImageView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm facing error in using this view
Code is as following:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

i tried checking dependencies, it didn't work

Comment: could you share you error

Comment: you have need to add dependency in gradle file than you can use it in xml

Answer (score 0):

What is the error?
I simply add
`implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'`
to the apps build.gradle dependencies and copied your code in the xml and it worked.